# Função recursiva

Tags: c, recursão

Alguem consegue me ajudar com essa função recursiva? É pra ela calcular o maximo divisor comum entre dois numeros mas nao sei o que tem de errado na minha função.

```
    int mdc(int m, int n){
        int aux;
        if(n>m || n<0){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            aux=mdc(n, m % n);
            return aux;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a condição de parada para o algoritimo de euclides (usado pra achar mdc) é quando encontra um resto = 0 e quando ocorre isso retornar o divisor que levou esse resto ser 0

```
if(n == 0 ){
    return m;
}
```

N depois da primeira chamada da função é o resto de uma divisão e M é o divisor que levou ao resto

Comment: Deu certo!!! Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O maximo divisor comum (mdc) dos inteiros x e y é o maior inteiro que é divisível por x e y. É definido como segue:

mdc(x, y) = y, se x >= y e x mod y=0

mdc(x, y) = mdc (y, x), se x < y

mdc(x, y) = mdc (y, x mod y), caso contrario (se x > y).

```
int mdc(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return mdc(y, x);
    }
    else {
        if (x % y == 0)
            return y;
        else
            return mdc(y, x%y);
    }

}
```